# How to generate .csproj file in visual studio 2019?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, csproj

We accidentally deleted the .csproj file of our android project in xamarin.forms. Is there any way to generate it again?

Comment: 1.Right Click on the Solution -Add - New project - Android - Blank App;
2.Add a reference to PCL project (Right click on References - Projects - Click on PCL Project)
3.Install the Xamarin.Forms Nuget Package (with the same version of the other projects) into Android Project
4.Go to your backup folder and copy the Resources and Properties folder

Comment: Retrieve it from your code repository (git, SVN, etc.)

Comment: Did you try to restore from the recycle bin?